# Input field showing different size in iOS

Tags: html, ios, css

I have an input field with a background and a fixed width/height. It looks good in all the browsers on my desktop. But for some reason it looks bigger on the **iPad** and **iPhone**.

I tried several tricks in Css but nothing worked so far.

```
width: 120px !important;
background-image:url('../img/header-input.png');
height: 30px;
-webkit-appearance: none !important;
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
border-radius:0;
@include border-radius(0);
outline: none;
border: none;
```

Comment: Did you try `-webkit-text-size-adjust`?

Comment: Do you mean this: font-size-adjust: none?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Be careful, as far as I know Safari browser in iOS adds extra padding in the input fields.

Try using this code inside your css:

```
padding: 0;
```

Comment: As an additional note, iOS add an extra margin too (something like `margin: 0 1px`).

Answer (score 2):

Add this between your :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

and if that doesn't work you can set styles for your phone/tablet using queries:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */  
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */ 
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply I just tried the meta tag, but it's still not working. For the @media it might work for the iPhone but not for iPad.

Comment: Try the ipad query? I don't see any reason for it not to work

Answer (score 1):

add this inside your header

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```