# Absolutely positioned input width on mobile safari

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

I have an input that is absolutely positioned inside a container. The container is fixed width `200` and the input is fixed with `160` with a margin of `20` on the left. This produces the result you would expect on Chrome:

[image]

But on mobile safari... it looks like this:

[image]

[Here is a minimum reproducible bug](https://github.com/samcorcos/mobile_safari_bug2). Instructions on how to get it running are in the readme.

This bug does not appear when the inner component is a `div`, but appears to be specific to `input`.

How does one format an absolutely-positioned text input on mobile safari so that it aligns the same way it does on Chrome, Safari, and Firefox?

Comment: Mmhmm... and what is your question?

Comment: @ObsidianAge I went ahead and updated the post with a question at the end: > How does one format an absolutely-positioned text input on mobile safari so that it aligns the same way it does on Chrome, Safari, and Firefox?

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle? Would be easier to see changes made. Thanks

Comment: @samcorcos Please see my solution below and let me know if it works? Thanks!

Comment: @GurtejSingh unfortunately that didn't solve it :(

Comment: @samcorcos oh. That's odd, as you can see in my screen shot that is fixed in the simulator. Are you sure that you are adding the padding? Can you please update your Git code? I'll take a look? Thanks!

Comment: @samcorcos I tried to make changes by forking your repo, and I was able to find the place to fix this. I tested it on my simulator and it seems to be working. Please see if you can merge this pull request into your repo and test it out : https://github.com/samcorcos/mobile_safari_bug2/pull/1. Hope it works this time! Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `padding:0` to your `input` field and it should solve the issue. This seems like a known issue in Safari for iOS, as it adds extra padding by default in input fields.

Took some help from here to fix it:

[Input field showing different size in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552908/input-field-showing-different-size-in-ios)

Could not find relevant place to fix it in your code in GIT. Guess I am new to react :)

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot attached post-fix]